# How to make function which can handle with diffetent number of parameters with php?

Tags: php

I want to edit user's information. User have a attributes:

```
User:
 name
 password
 enabled
 group
```

It's fine if i edit all attributes at once - i just get 4 parameters from POST and use function for save changes:

```
function editUser($oldname,$newname,$password,$enabled,$group){
    //**some code**//
    $mgroup->getMember()->setName($newname);
    $mgroup->getMember()->setPassword($password);
    $mgroup->getMember()->setEnabled($enabled);
    $mgroup->getMember()->setGroup($group);
    //**some code**//
}
```

But if i am editing just a one or two parameters i cant use my function.
So how can i change function depending on the number of parameters?

For example i edit just `pass` and `enabled` attributes, for this my function gonna do:

```
function editUser($oldname,$password,$enabled){
    //**some code**//
    $mgroup->getMember()->setPassword($password);
    $mgroup->getMember()->setEnabled($enabled);
    //**some code**//
}
```

It's possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such cases you usually just pass `NULL` as argument for the fields where you don't change anything and verify in your setter function:

```
if ($val !== NULL) {
    $this->property = $val; // set it!
}
```

---

If you have really a lot of arguments; I'd pass an array to improve readability:

```
editUser(array('oldname' => …, 'newname' => …, …));
```

And change the function to:

```
function editUser ($array) {
    if (isset($array['newname']))
        $mgroup->getMember()->setName($array['newname']);
    // …
}
```

Comment: sorry i failed in question title.( My question about function with different number of parameters.

Comment: @KliverMax yeah. As said: pass NULL for the parameters you don't use?

Comment: Oh sorry, i was read your answer badly. Was thought that you tell how to take POST parameters.

Comment: Passing `NULL` for arguments you don't use is fine so long as you don't have a lot of arguments. When the number of arguments grow, a line like `editUser("foo", "bar", null, null, null, true, null, "baz", null)` becomes increasingly hard to read and maintain. There are better solutions in this case. See other answers.

Comment: @bwoebi: You could also just copy-paste my answer below. ;-)

Comment: @Simon Didn't see your answer until now ;-) Btw. looking forward to see named parameters in PHP 5.6… https://wiki.php.net/rfc/named_params

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
function editUser($oldname,$newname,$password,$enabled = true,$group = DEFAULT_GRP_ID)
```

You should be abled to call editUser with 3, 4 or 5 parameters. PHP isn't like java where you need to redeclare methods.

D.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like so:

```
function editUser($oldname,$newname,$password,$enabled,$group){
    if($newname != null){
        $mgroup->getMember()->setName($newname);
    }
    //rinse and repeat for all others
}
```

Then when you call the function pass null for values you don't want to change.

```
editUser("oldName", "newName", null, null, "group");
```

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use associated array like `array('oldname'=>$oldname,.....)` then use value which is not null

Answer (score 1):

Can you define default values for each variable in your function?

```
function editUser($oldname='',$newname='',$password='',$enabled='',$group='') 
{
if !empty($oldname){do something}
....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution to this is to give your arguments default values, check if they're null inside the function and only deal with them if they're not.

```
function editUser($oldname, $password, $enabled = null, $newname = null, etc.){
    //**some code**//
    $mgroup->getMember()->setName($newname);
    $mgroup->getMember()->setPassword($password);
    if ($newname != null)
        $mgroup->getMember()->setEnabled($enabled);
    if ($group != null)
        $mgroup->getMember()->setGroup($group);
    //**some code**//
}
```

One drawback with this method is that you cannot leave `$enabled = null` implicitly and still set `$newname = something` explicitly (i.e. you need to call `editUser($oldname, $password, null, $newname, etc.)`, which is both hard to read and maintain when the number of arguments grow. A solution to this is to use *named variables*. Since PHP does not directly supported named variables, the manual suggests [passing an associative array as argument](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php):

```
function editUser($args) {
    $member = $mgroup->getMember();
    $member->setName($args["newname"]);
    $member->setPassword($args["password"]);
    if (isset($args["enabled"]))
        $member->setEnabled($args["enabled"]);
    ...
}
```